# Roots of a irreducible polynomial are linearly independent over a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

**Question.** When does a irreducible polynomial contains linearly independent roots over a finite field?

**Motivation.** For a finite cyclic Galois extension $E/F$, if $\alpha\in E$ generates a [normal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis), then for any intermediate extension $E/M/F$, $M=F\left[\operatorname{Tr}_{E/M}(\alpha)\right],$ where $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/M}(\alpha)$ is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace) of $\alpha$.

In particular, for any extension $E/F$ of finite fields, let $|F|=p^n$. It's a standard fact that $E/F$ is Galois and $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)=\left<\sigma_{p^n}\right>,$ where $\sigma_{p^n}(x)=x^{p^n}.$ If there is a canonical way to choose a normal basis in some nice cases, one could then compute the corresponding intermediate extensions from the above theorem.

Let $|F|=p^n$ and $\left[E:F\right]=d$. Let $\omega$ be a generator of the (cyclic) multiplicative group $E^{\times}$ so that $E=\{0,\omega,...,\omega^{p^{nd}-1}=1\}$. The minimal polynomial $p_{\omega_k}$ of $\omega^{k}$ over $F$ is given by $(x-\omega^k)(x-\omega^{kp^n})(x-\omega^{kp^{2n}})...$ by conjugating $\omega^k$ by the automorphism $\sigma_{p^n}$. Note that $\deg p_{\omega^k}=d$ iff $(k,p^{nd}-1)=1$ and such $\omega^k$ is exactly the roots of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{p^{nd}-1}$ and $\Phi_{p^{nd}-1}$ factors into irreducible factors of degree $d$ over $F$.

To determine whether an element $\omega^k$ that generates a normal basis, it is necessary and sufficient to *determine a irreducible factor of $\Phi_{p^{nd}-1}$ with linearly independent roots*. It's not hard too see that every irreducible polynomial over a finite field $F$ is a factor of some cyclotomic polynomial over $F$. Thus goes the above question.

**Example.** For $\Bbb F_{8}/\Bbb F_{2}$ the polynomial $\Phi_7=x^6+...+x+1$ factors into $(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1)$ over $\Bbb F_2$. The roots of $x^3+x+1$ cannot be linearly independent as the trace of a root is $0$, which is just the sum of all the three roots. So $x^3+x^2+1$ gives a normal basis in this case. Naturally one asks when does the linearly independency of the roots is equivalent to a non-zero trace. This happens when $|E| = |F|^{|F|^m}$ for some $m$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4808989/413924) answer.

**Example.** Let $\operatorname{char}(F)=p$ and let $m=p^{nd}-1$. Then $\Phi_m$ is irreducible over $F$ if and only if $m$ is a prime and $p$ is a generator for the multiplicative group $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^{\times}$. In this case roots of $\Phi_m$ clearly give a normal basis for $E/F$.

---

**Update.** I quoted the motivation part below again:

> **Motivation.** For a finite cyclic Galois extension $E/F$, if $\alpha\in E$ generates a [normal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_basis), then for any intermediate extension $E/M/F$, $M=F\left[\operatorname{Tr}_{E/M}(\alpha)\right],$ where $\operatorname{Tr}_{E/M}(\alpha)$ is the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace) of $\alpha$.

This is *not* really a good motivation for us to *find a normal basis element* for cyclic cyclotomic extensions over $\Bbb Q$, as the primitive root of unity is automatically a normal basis element.

It is *neither* a good motivation for us to *compute a primitive element for intermediate extension between two finite fields*. Since the multiplicative group of every finite field is cyclic, the primitive element for the intermediate extension is then clear after one finds a cyclic generator $\omega$ and makes a suitable exponent.

The motivation part, however, still could be useful for other scenarios. Also note that the conclusion could be sharpened as "$\operatorname{Tr}_{E/M}(\alpha)$ is a normal basis element of $M/F$."